# Access 365: update table row using split form

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, office365

I have a very rookie question regarding making a simple Access database but for some reason I'm having trouble finding the proper keywords to adequately Google the problem. I'm certain the solution is going to be a simple toggle or setting I need to flip somewhere but I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

I have a table, tblClients. Each row has name, address, etc. I manually inputted a bunch of entries in here from datasheet view. I created a split form, frmClients, which will be to update client info in a more user-friendly fashion. At the moment, when the user makes any modifications in the form view and hit save, it appears to succeed but the actual data in the table row hasn't been modified. Do I need to change a setting somewhere or is there a different mechanism to post changes other than Ctrl+S or the save icon?

If there is necessary additional information I neglected to provide, please let me know. Thanks for your help.

-Marissa

Comment: Well, Save and Ctrl+S both work for me. But I am not using Access 365, just Access 2010. Cannot replicate issue. However, neither is needed in order to save data. As long as form and controls are BOUND, record entry/edit is committed to table when: 1) close table/query/form; or 2) move to another record; or 3) run code or click Save or Ctrl+S.

Comment: I regressed to Access 2010 just now, for unrelated reasons. Now that I've done that the table/form is behaving as expected. I don't know what I changed.... but it works now. Thanks for your input June, much appreciated.